# Array.map + parseInt

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

```
var timeSplit = timeCaption.innerText.trim().split(' ');
```

will yield an Array of `["10:00", "–", "18:00"]`

```
var startStr = timeSplit[0].split(':');
```

will yield an Array of `["10", "00"]`

```
var res = startStr.map(parseInt);
```

will yield an Array of `[10, NaN]`

however

```
var res = startStr.map(function (x) {
   return parseInt(x);
});
```

works correctly and will yield the "expected" Array of `[10, 0]`

I expect each string to be passed to `parseInt` which returns the correct interger value (and doing that separately also yields the correct result, just like the working code).

What am I missing here?

**edit: I myself voted to close this question. Pretty obvious mistake. Thx guys!**

Comment: Just a heads up, if your wanting to shorten this to avoid the function / return syntax and are able to use es6 features.  you can just do ->   `var res = startStr.map(x=>parseInt(x));`  as such not a million miles of what you did.

Comment: yeah I know, im hacking together a plugin where I didn't set up es2015 transpilers, just totally "forgot" how map works -_- thx though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`parseInt` accepts 2 arguments:

1. string to be parsed
2. radix

`.map` calls your function with 3 arguments:

1. the value
2. the index
3. array

If you think about it,

```
parseInt("00", 1)
```

doesn't really make sense and it returns `NaN`. `parseInt` accepts radixes between 2 and 36.

Comment: yeah you are right, thx

Comment: Unbelievable that I couldn't find out that by myself before reading this answer X-(

Comment: Useful note:  When `parseInt` is given a radix of `0`, it interprets the radix as 10 unless the string starts with `0x` or `0X`, in which case it interprets characters using a radix of 16 (skipping the `0x` prefix of course), which is why the first number of the array often turns maps as expected, but the second number is `NaN`, and subsequent indices have unanticipated results.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `parseInt` is the radix, or base (like 10, 16, etc, defaults to base 10). `.map` passes two arguments to the callback, the value at that index, and also the index. So you're calling `parseInt(10, 0)` which is trying to figure out what 10 is in base 0.

Answer (score 1):

`.map()` calls the function with 3 arguments: The array element, the array index, and the array. `parseInt` takes 2 parameters: the string to parse, and the radix in which to parse it.

So `startStr.map(parseInt)` is calling:

```
parseInt("10", 0, startStr);
parseInt("00", 1, startStr);
```

Apparently `parseInt()` treats `radix = 0` as no radix, so it defaults to base 10. But `radix = 1` doesn't make any sense at all, so it returns `NaN`.